# ifoddpage not working

Tags: conditionals, double-sided

I'm testing [`ifoddpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifoddpage) but it seems to say that every page is even:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand\printpage{%
Page is \thepage. It is \ifoddpage odd\else even\fi.
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\printpage 

\lipsum

\printpage

\end{document}
```

outputs:

> Page 2. It is even.

and then

> Page 3. It is even.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to include `\checkoddpage` in your custom macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand\printpage{%
Page is \thepage. It is \checkoddpage\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi.
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\printpage

\lipsum

\printpage

\end{document}
```