# LaTeX gets confused about what page it is

Tags: page-numbering, tufte, marginnote

The title should explain the problem.

```
\documentclass[justified, symmetric]{tufte-book}
\geometry{paperwidth = 8in, paperheight = 10.5in, right = 2.2in, marginparwidth = 1.5in}
\usepackage{ifthen, lipsum, showframe}
\begin{document}
%  ------------------------------
\textbf{\thepage} \marginnote{A margin note} \par
\lipsum[1-5]
\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{\thepage} \marginnote{\raggedleft A margin note} \par
\lipsum[6-9]
\vspace{0.6cm}

\textbf{\thepage} \marginnote{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{A margin note}{\raggedleft A margin note}} \par % <---- this note should be on the left side of the margin
\lipsum[6-9]
%  ------------------------------
\end{document}
```

The wrong page numbering also results in a wrong display of the margin note:

[image]

To be fair, a simple `\clearpage` before the third margin note solves the problem, but having to solve things manually is both impractical and annoying.

Comment: It's a known issue that `\thepage` is not a reliable way to get the current page number in most situations. See for example https://texfaq.org/FAQ-oddpage, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wrongpn and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473903/35864 and

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Is there some more reliable counter that gives the correct number?

Comment: never use `\thepage` in a document, latex is not confused, it is just not telling you what you expected it to tell you. Use `\pageref` to get a page number.

Comment: The `ifoddpage` package from the first link sounds like it could be what you are looking for. Otherwise `\pageref`+`\label` from the second link.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how do I use `\pageref` as the argument of the `\isodd{}` command?

Comment: `\pageref` should work in ifthenelse (as I took precautions to make it work)  just set a `\label` on the page you want to reference, but you may find specific tests like the ifoddpage mentioned above to be easier

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74010/35864 might be more helpful. Since this question is about even/odd the `\pageref` duplicate might not be the best one.